# Tree-like Connectors in Table

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tree, tabular

Take a look at my fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DmcEB/46/

As you can see, it's a little wonky.  I want it to look a little more like this:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it just making sure that only those cells have the "effect" on them? Does this look right? http://i.imgur.com/2Q64K.png Or is there more to the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case it does happen to be this easy:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/DmcEB/49/

Change your selector from this:

```
.geniusPicks tr>td
```

to this:

```
.geniusPicks tr > td:first-child
```

That will select only the first `td` in each `tr`. You're already slicing out the irrelevant `td`s.